# How to save multiple plots in a folder

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my program in python and I am trying to save multiple plots in a single folder but it doesn't seem to work. How could I do this please?

```
for i in range(0:244):
plt.figure()
y = numpy.array(Data_EMG[i,:])
x = pylab.linspace(EMG_start, EMG_stop, Amount_samples)
plt.xlabel('Time(ms)')
plt.ylabel('EMG voltage(microV)')
pylab.plot(x, y)
pylab.show(block=True)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all check the identation. Hopefully your code actually reads

```
for i in range(0:244):
    plt.figure()
    y = numpy.array(Data_EMG[i,:])
    x = pylab.linspace(EMG_start, EMG_stop, Amount_samples)
    plt.xlabel('Time(ms)')
    plt.ylabel('EMG voltage(microV)')
    pylab.plot(x, y)
    pylab.show(block=True)
```

At each iteration you completely generate a new figure. That´s very ineffective. Also you just plot your figure on the screen and not actually save it. Better is

```
from os import path
data = numpy.array(Data_EMG)                 # convert complete dataset into numpy-array
x = pylab.linspace(EMG_start, EMG_stop, Amount_samples) # doesn´t change in loop anyway

outpath = "path/of/your/folder/"

fig, ax = plt.subplots()        # generate figure with axes
image, = ax.plot(x,data[0])     # initialize plot
ax.xlabel('Time(ms)')
ax.ylabel('EMG voltage(microV)')
plt.draw()
fig.savefig(path.join(outpath,"dataname_0.png")

for i in range(1, len(data)):
    image.set_data(x,data[i])
    plt.draw()
    fig.savefig(path.join(outpath,"dataname_{0}.png".format(i))
```

Should be much faster.

Comment: why the comma in the original `image, = ax.plot(x,data[0])` but not in `image.set_data(x,data[i])` ?

Comment: The comma is here only to tell ax.plot(x,data[0]) that image is affected only to the first returned value and to discard the rest.
The variable is named `image` and not `image,`.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [savefig](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) function.

```
for i in range(0:244):
    plt.figure()
    y = numpy.array(Data_EMG[i,:])
    x = pylab.linspace(EMG_start, EMG_stop, Amount_samples)
    plt.xlabel('Time(ms)')
    plt.ylabel('EMG voltage(microV)')
    plt.savefig('EMG {0}.jpg'.format(i))
    plt.close()
```