# Plotting multiple scatter plots with acceptable speed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a lot of data to create scatter plots for, with each individual plot needing to be saved. Each plot shares the same axis. Currently I have this which works:

```
            for i in dct:
                plt.figure()
                plt.scatter(time_values, dct[i])
                plt.title(i)
                plt.xlabel("Time")
                plt.ylabel("values")
                plt.xticks(x_labels,rotation=90)

                plt.savefig(os.path.join('some_file_path','image{}.png'.format(str(self.image_counter))))
                plt.close('all')
```

However, it is very slow at actually creating the graphs. The answer here [How could I save multiple plots in a folder using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630748/how-could-i-save-multiple-plots-in-a-folder-using-python) does what I want, however only for a normal plot. Is there anyway I can implement something like this with a scatter plot? I have tried converting by data into a 2D array, however my x_axis values are a string and so it does not accept the array

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can plot scatter plots with `plt.plot(x, y, 'o')` and re-use that code by example.